# How can I write Value Help datas in the input field?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

In my Sapui5 application, I have created an editable ValueHelp field in the table. Later, I want the data I selected from the ValueHelp Dialog to be written in my input field. I used the following methods for this:

Input:

```
  <Input id="inputUretimLks" value="{UretimLokasyon}" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="false" valueHelpRequest="onUretimLok"/>
```

ValueHelp dialog:

```
 <TableSelectDialog id="UretimLokTable" noDataText="Veri Bulunamadı" title="Üretim Lokasyon" search=".uretimSearch" confirm=".uretimValueHelpClose"
        cancel=".uretimValueHelpClose" items="{ path : '/UretimVhSet', sorter : { path : 'UrLks', descending : false } }">
        <ColumnListItem selected="{selected}">
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{UrLks}" text="{UrLksTnm}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
        <columns>
            <Column width="12em">
                <header>
                    <Text text="Lokasyon"/>
                </header>
            </Column>
        </columns>
</TableSelectDialog>
```

Confirm code :

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
                aUretim = oModel.getProperty("/UretimVhSet"),
                oInput = this.byId("inputUretimLks");

            var bHasSelected = aUretim.some(function(oUretim) {
                if (oUretim.selected) {
                    oInput.setValue(oUretim.UrLks);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (!bHasSelected) {
                oInput.setValue(null);
            }
```

I know I can't use 'some' here. But how will the right solution be?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `oModel.getProperty("/UretimVhSet")`. The property `UretimVhSet`seems to be no array, so you can't use `some`. Maybe binding problems in dialog? Can you show the dialog open function?

Comment: Why don't you use the parameter of your `valueHelpClose`? It should contain the selected value. Using `getProperty` to load a collection from OData will not work.

Comment: I get the data from ODATA service. For this I need to create a json model in the controller. I can do binding this way. I know this but how do I do this? I'm new on this, can you please guide how to do it?

Comment: You don't need to create a JSON model. You already have everything you need. Just connect the dots.

Comment: If the number of data is small, the use of combobox is more accurate. This is how I solved my problem. Less work and easier use.